# How to draw image with base64 encoded image data on android canvas

Tags: android, image, base64, android-canvas

I have an image data encoded in base64 format;

```
String data="data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAgAAZABkAAD/7A......62IV/9k=";
```

Now I want to draw this image on canvas;

How to do it?

Any help..

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
byte[] byteArray= Base64.decode(yourbase64string, Base64.DEFAULT);
Bitmap image= BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray, 0, byteArray.length);
```

And then

```
canvas.drawBitmap(image,x,y, paint);
```